# Perl file comparison and write values

Tags: perl

I Have 2 files I want to compare the values in `file1` with `file2` and replace value of `file1` if value found different from `file2`.

If there are any additional values in `file2` then it can be ignored.

`file1`:

```
value1 equalto txt

value2 equalto doc 

value3 equalto new
```

`file2`:

```
value1 equalto   doc   

value2 equalto   ref                       replace this value in  file1

value3 equalto  txt                       replace this value in  file1

value4 equalto  test                      ignore this if not found in file1
```

Comment: The order of the values matters? You need to read both files and store the data in a hash for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $ pass = 0;
my ( $first, $rest, %hash_of_lines );
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    ( $first, $rest ) = split / /, $_, 2;
    if ($pass == 0) {
        $hash_of_lines{$first} = $_;
    }
    elsif ( exists $hash_of_lines{$first} ) {
        $hash_of_lines{$first} = $_;
    }
    $pass++ if eof;
}
for my $key (sort keys %hash_of_lines) {
    print $hash_of_lines{$key}, "\n";
}
1;
```

Use this like:

```
$ ./build file1 file2
```

Comment: Thanks to both the above of you... I think i did not put it properly just clarifying, file1 has some variables it need to modify those variables in file2, so whatever lines file1 has, and if those variables are found in file2 then those needs to be replaced with file1 variable.

Comment: @Sriam: If I understand correctly, just reverse the order of the filename arguments; viz. ./build file2 file1

Comment: No James the above script lists the equivalent values in both files, but in my case I have a set of values in one file  with "name" "=" "value" that needs to be replaced in the other file with matching "name"... i hope its clear this time.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($to_change, $reference) = @ARGV[0,1];
my %pairs_ref;
my %pairs_change;
my $line = qr/^(\w+)\s+equalto\s+(\w+)/;

# read the reference file
open (my $fhr, '<', $reference) or die "Cannot read from file $reference: $!";
while (<$fhr>) {
   if (/$line/) {
      my ($param, $value) = ($1, $2);
      $pairs_ref{$param} = $value;  # store all pairs
   }
}
close $fhr;

# read the file to be modified (note: we're not using in-place modification!)
open (my $fhc, '<', $to_change) or die "Cannot read from file $to_change: $!";
while (<$fhc>) {
   if (/$line/) {
      my $param = $1;
      # if the parameter appeared in the reference file, set the value to the reference
      # value (does no damage if they're identical anyway)
      if (defined $pairs_ref{$param}) {
         $pairs_change{$param} = $pairs_ref{$param}; 
      }
   }
}
close $fhc;

# print to the output file (that way we're not overwriting the original information)
open (my $fhn, '>', "file3") or die "Cannot write to file3: $!";
foreach my $param (sort keys %pairs_change) {
   print $fhn "$param equalto $pairs_change{$param}\n\n";
}
close $fhn;
```

It's simple, and I only used the information that was given in your question, so I don't know whether this is indeed what you're looking for. I did not take into account any differences in the number of blank spaces or so.

The resulting file (which I called 'file3') looks like this:

```
value1 equalto doc

value2 equalto ref

value3 equalto txt
```

The script is to be invoked like this:

```
./script.pl file1 file2
```

Comment: thanks , i just needed a slight modification which i listed below.

Comment: @Sriram I interpret your comment just like James did, so I too would tell you to simply swap 'file1' and 'file2' in script invocation to change which of them is the reference file. If this does not address your need, then please edit your question and show us what the result should actually look like. Thanks.

Comment: Hi ... when i run the above script wiyj options file1 file2 I see a file3 being created but its empty , even swaping the file gets me the same result ...

Comment: @Sriram It works for me, I just tested it again. file3 is just like what I wrote in my post.

Comment: File3 was empty for me ... $ cat file1
provisioning.include.hcm.app.hcm-coresetup.cluster.name=CoreSetupCluster
offering.hcm.OrderOrchestration.ess=scm-internal.oracleoutsourcing.com:10617
provisioning.include.hcm.techstack.odi.restart.interval.seconds=4000
$ cat file2
provisioning.include.hcm.app.hcm-coresetup.cluster.name=CoreSetupCluster
offering.hcm.OrderOrchestration.ess=scm-internal.oracleoutsourcing.com:10617
provisioning.include.hcm.techstack.odi.restart.interval.seconds=3200
$ ./verify.pl file1 file2
$ cat file3
$

Comment: @Sriram As I said, I wrote the script based on the information you gave in your post. Your file1 looks totally different from what you gave as an example - which is fair enough, but in that case OF COURSE you have to modify the code. You probably didn't even have a closer look at how it works. I've got the impression you just want us to solve your problem without making any kind of effort yourself!

Comment: @canavin Hi... As I am new to perl... I am still trying to understand the script, sorry if it sounds like a trouble, that was not my intention... I will take it from here ... I did try few things using foreach loop comparing files and writing which did not go well :(, in the above i changed the equalto to = will check this more and understand. Thanks again